# Error : undefined reference to MainWindow::~MainWindow | Qt under gcc, VSCode

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, linker-errors

I imported a project from Qt Creator over to another PC, and am trying to get it to run under VSCode. For the record, I was able to run it from Qt Creator on the previous PC. After struggling a bunch to get the code to pass compiling, I encounter a problem involving the linker.
The problem is encountered when building the project. The build prompt, passed on from the tasks.json file, goes as follows:

```
F:\fortan\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "F:\[...]\main.cpp" -o "F:\[...]\main.exe" -lstdc++ -L F:\Soft\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_32\lib -l Qt5Widgets -l Qt5Core -I F:\Soft\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_32\include
```

The error message goes:

```
[...]/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)'
[...]/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to 'MainWindow::~MainWindow()'
[...]/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to 'MainWindow::~MainWindow()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the code for `main.cpp` (nothing out of the ordinary):

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"

    #include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
    
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show(); //line 9 is here
        return a.exec();
    }
```

It seems the creation of the **MainWindow w** object causes the problem. The error seems to come from the *linker*, which I don't understand.
The MainWindow class, and its constructor and destructor, are declared as follows (`mainwindow.h`):

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore/QString>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
[...]
```

and defined such as this (`mainwindow.cpp`):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
[...]
```

After double-checking all includes and correct declaration/implementation of the constructors, I tried linking the .h file in the gcc prompt, with -L to the project directory and -l (call me superstitious), to no avail.

Comment: In `F:\fortan\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "F:\[...]\main.cpp" -o "F:\[...]\main.exe" -lstdc++ -L F:\Soft\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_32\lib -l Qt5Widgets -l Qt5Core -I F:\Soft\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_32\include` you are only compiling `main.cpp`. You forgot to compile the file that implements `MainWindow`.

Comment: Also how are you running moc and uic (and possibly rcc)? To use VSCode with the Qt framework you probably should use CMake and the CMake tools extension. It's more work / somewhat difficult to manually specify all of the steps especially when your project gets more complicated.